# How do I stop onChange event from happening when I delete the current selection

Tags: events, onchange, selectize.js

I'm using Selectize and after I make an initial selection on a pulldown the onChange occurs. However when I manually delete the entry in order to make a new selection, onChange fires with an empty selection. Is there a way to stop this from occurring?

Would like to stop onChange event until a make a new selection rather than clearing the first one.